# Python: Breaking out of the SteamCMD prompt

Tags: python, windows, steam

Please bear with me as this is my first major Python project.

I am trying to create a utility in Python to assist with SteamCMD functions.  For those who are not aware of SteamCMD or its functionality, it is essentially a CLI-only tool for the Steam gaming platform and designed for server administrators that don't need the full Steam client.  Here is a link to the developer reference page for the tool: [SteamCMD Developer Community](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD) (I'm only working on Windows compatibility at the moment).

This executable requires that upon first run that you execute SteamCMD.exe directly so that it can download fully and initialize.  This is my problematic area as the tool drops you into a "Steam >" prompt upon executing the tool.  I cannot find a way to have my Python script break out of this "Steam >" prompt.

Here's my code so far:

```
        print "Update SteamCMD"

    # Set SteamCMD Install Directory
    # 1) Prompt user for installed path
    # 2) Determine if input was provided
    # 3) If input was provided, trim and update SCMD_Install_Path string
    # 4) Determine if directory exists and if not, error and loop
    path_valid = False
    while path_valid == False:
        SCMD_Install_Path = raw_input("SteamCMD Install Location [C:\Program Files\(x86)\SteamCMD]: ")
        if SCMD_Install_Path == '':
            SCMD_Install_Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\SteamCMD"
        else:
            SCMD_Install_Path = SCMD_Install_Path.rstrip('\\')
        if os.path.exists(SCMD_Install_Path):
            print "SteamCMD install found. Continuing..."
            path_valid = True
        else:
            print "SteamCMD install was not found. Please specify a valid location."
    print "Updating SteamCMD..."
    os.chdir(SCMD_Install_Path)
    os.system("SteamCMD.exe")
    print "Update complete!"
    os.system("cls")
```

As of now, I need to manually type "quit" at the "Steam >" prompt so that my python utility can continue.  Here's a screenshot of the utility running:
[image: SteamCMD Quitting]

Any insight you guys can provide would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain commands to steamcmd.exe so try using

```
 os.system("SteamCMD.exe +quit")
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to select this as an answer!